# Back button on Chrome/Edge behaves differently compared to Firefox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

The back button on Chrome/Edge takes the tab back to another domain I'm using to give a token to the user after they login over there - instead of the page in-between to verify the token on the react project.

When a user tries going back on Firefox, they land on the page in between that redirects them to the main landing page. But in Chrome/Edge it takes them back before that page to the login page on a different domain.

When the user first lands on the page - I redirect them with *history.push()*. If they come back using the back button - I redirect them back with *history.goForward()* using the *useHistory* from *react-router*.

**Any ideas how to get it to work the same way on Chrome/Edge ?**

```
const history = useHistory();
useEffect(() => {

if (isUserLoggedIn()) {
  history.goForward(); // send back to main page
} else {
  fetch(checksomething())
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((response) =>
    history.push("/main")
    );
} },[]);
```

Comment: `history.push()` (actually `history.pushState()`) does not "redirect" a user. I think you misunderstand how the `window.history` API works - or are you referring to a different `history` object?

Comment: I'm using the history object provided by react-router to change the url after verifying the token on react.

Comment: please add minimal relevant code of routing process